# R-squared on test data

Tags: r, linear-regression

I fit a linear regression model on 75% of my data set that includes ~11000 observations and 143 variables:

```
gl.fit <- lm(y[1:ceiling(length(y)*(3/4))] ~ ., data= x[1:ceiling(length(y)*(3/4)),]) #3/4 for training
```

and I got an R^2 of 0.43. I then tried predicting on my test data using the rest of the data:

```
ytest=y[(ceiling(length(y)*(3/4))+1):length(y)]
x.test <- cbind(1,x[(ceiling(length(y)*(3/4))+1):length(y),]) #The rest for test
yhat <- as.matrix(x.test)%*%gl.fit$coefficients  #Calculate the predicted values
```

I now would like to calculate the R^2 value on my test data. Is there any easy way to calculate that?

Thank you

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86314/higher-r-squared-value-on-test-data-than-training-data) on CrossValidated.

Comment: @nrussell Thanks; I used the formula in the mentioned question and got a negative number (-0.59) as my R^2 value. I have a doubt about my lm model, should I add an intercept (I assume R does it automatically)? Then why am I getting negative R^2?

Comment: Did you use the formula in the question or the formula in the comment below the question? Because the formula in the question is incorrect - see @Panos's comment on that question.

Comment: @nrussell I used the one in comment:`errors <- (ytest - yhat)` `1 - sum(errors^2)/sum((ytest-mean(ytest))^2)` and I get -0.59!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First, this is not a good way to use `lm(...)`. `lm(...)` is meant to be used with a data frame, with the formula expressions referencing columns in the df. So, assuming your data is in two vectors `x` and `y`,

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
x <- 1:11000
y <- 3+0.1*x + rnorm(11000,sd=1000)

df <- data.frame(x,y)
# training set
train <- sample(1:nrow(df),0.75*nrow(df))   # random sample of 75% of data

fit <- lm(y~x,data=df[train,])
```

Now `fit` has the model based on the training set. Using `lm(...)` this way allows you, for example to generate predictions without all the matrix multiplication.

The second problem is the definition of R-squared. The [conventional definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) is:

> 1 - SS.residuals/SS.total

For the training set, *and the training set ONLY*,

> SS.total = SS.regression + SS.residual

so

> SS.regression = SS.total - SS.residual,

and therefore

> R.sq = SS.regression/SS.total

so R.sq is the fraction of variability in the dataset that is explained by the model, and will always be between 0 and 1.

You can see this below.

```
SS.total      <- with(df[train,],sum((y-mean(y))^2))
SS.residual   <- sum(residuals(fit)^2)
SS.regression <- sum((fitted(fit)-mean(df[train,]$y))^2)
SS.total - (SS.regression+SS.residual)
# [1] 1.907349e-06
SS.regression/SS.total     # fraction of variation explained by the model
# [1] 0.08965502
1-SS.residual/SS.total     # same thing, for model frame ONLY!!! 
# [1] 0.08965502          
summary(fit)$r.squared     # both are = R.squared
# [1] 0.08965502
```

But this *does not* work with the test set (e.g., when you make predictions from a model).

```
test <- -train
test.pred <- predict(fit,newdata=df[test,])
test.y    <- df[test,]$y

SS.total      <- sum((test.y - mean(test.y))^2)
SS.residual   <- sum((test.y - test.pred)^2)
SS.regression <- sum((test.pred - mean(test.y))^2)
SS.total - (SS.regression+SS.residual)
# [1] 8958890

# NOT the fraction of variability explained by the model
test.rsq <- 1 - SS.residual/SS.total  
test.rsq
# [1] 0.0924713

# fraction of variability explained by the model
SS.regression/SS.total 
# [1] 0.08956405
```

In this contrived example there is not much difference, but it is very possible to have an R-sq. value less than 0 (when defined this way).

If, for example, the model is a very poor predictor with the test set, then the residuals can actually be larger than the total variation in test set. This is equivalent to saying that the test set is modeled better using it's mean, than using the model derived from the training set.

I noticed that you use the first three quarters of your data as the training set, rather than taking a random sample (as in this example). If the dependance of `y` on `x` is non-linear, and the `x`'s are in order, then you could get a negative R-sq with the test set.

Regarding OP's comment below, one way to assess the model with a test set is by comparing in-model to out-of-model mean squared error (MSE).

```
mse.train <- summary(fit)$sigma^2
mse.test  <- sum((test.pred - test.y)^2)/(nrow(df)-length(train)-2)
```

If we assume that the training and test set are both normally distributed with the same variance and having means which follow the same model formula, then the ratio should have an F-distribution with (n.train-2) and (n.test-2) degrees of freedom. If the MSE's are significantly different based on an F-test, then the model does *not* fit the test data well.

Have you plotted your test.y and pred.y vs x?? This alone will tell you a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much for this elaborate example. In this case, what is the best way for me to assess my model on the test data set?

Comment: I just edited the response to bring it into alignment with the more conventional definition of R-sq, but the main conclusions are unchanged. Regarding your question, see my comments at the end.

Comment: Excellent answer, as usual. I changed my train/test set as you suggested to collect the points randomly. I am no longer getting negative R-squared for my test (assuming it has a meaning). I also calculated the training and test MSEs: 0.00056 for training, 0.00036 for test, ratio ~0.65. comparing with this: `qf(0.95,length(train)-2,length(test)-2) = 1.036603`, the model is doing something. Please correct me if I am making a mistake.

Comment: Well, since the out-of-model MSE is less than the MSE for the fit, it's hard to argue that the model doesn't work with the test data. Have you looked at the diagnostic plots `par(mfrow=c(2,2)); plot(fit)`?

Comment: I did, but I am not 100% sure on how to interpret the graphs. Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdufnw8jqr7gfzs/diag.pdf?dl=0. Can you please comment on that? Thanks

Comment: You either have a very large number of outliers, or your model is not adequate. The Q-Q plot should be a straight line. Your residuals have a much higher proportion of very large -ve and +ve values than would be expected from a normal distribution. Also, generally most points should have leverage < 0.1. The fact that your residuals have leverage as large as 1.0 is strongly suggestive of outliers. Read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf), especially Chapt. 7.

Answer (score 7):

Calculating R-squared on the testing data is a little tricky, as you have to remember what your baseline is. Your baseline projection is a mean of your **training** data.

Therefore, extending the example provided by @jlhoward above:

```
SS.test.total      <- sum((test.y - mean(df[train,]$y))^2)
SS.test.residual   <- sum((test.y - test.pred)^2)
SS.test.regression <- sum((test.pred - mean(df[train,]$y))^2)
SS.test.total - (SS.test.regression+SS.test.residual)
# [1] 11617720 not 8958890

test.rsq <- 1 - SS.test.residual/SS.test.total  
test.rsq
# [1] 0.09284556 not 0.0924713

# fraction of variability explained by the model
SS.test.regression/SS.test.total 
# [1] 0.08907705 not 0.08956405
```

Update: `miscTools::rSquared()` function makes an assumption that R-squared is calculated on the same dataset, on which the model is trained, as it calculates

```
yy <- y - mean(y)
```

behind the scenes in line 184 here: https://github.com/cran/miscTools/blob/master/R/utils.R

Comment: do you have any reference in the literature for using the mean of the training set as reference point? intuitively it seems convincing but not many people use it...

Answer (score 3):

If you want a function, the `miscTools` package has an `rSquared` function.

```
require(miscTools)
r2 <- rSquared(ytest, resid = ytest-yhat)
```

Comment: I couldn't find this package:                                              Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Haidar/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘micsTools’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

Comment: @H_A, typo on my part, sorry.  It is `miscTools`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I am still getting negative value for my R^2, I suspect that there is something wrong with my regression/prediction procedure.

Answer (score 2):

When you use an R2 measure on an (out-of-) sample, you loose certain aspects of the interpretation of the R2:

- the equivalence SSR total = SSR explained + SSR error
- The fact that R2 is equal to the squared of the correlation between y and predicted y
- The fact that R2 is in [0,1]

If you want to use R, I would recommend the function `modelr::rsquare`. Note this uses the SSR total from the test sample, not the training sample (as some people seem to advocate).

Here I take an example where our train data has only 3 points, there is hence a high risk that we are having a bad model, and hence a poor out-of-sample performance, Indeed, you can see that the R2 is negative!

```r
library(modelr)

train <- mtcars[c(1,3,4),]
test  <- mtcars[-c(1,3,4),]

mod <- lm(carb ~ drat, data = train)
```

Compute on train data:

```r
## train
y_train <- train$carb
SSR_y_train <- sum((y_train-mean(y_train))^2)

cor(fitted(mod), y_train)^2
#> [1] 0.2985092
rsquare(mod, train)
#> [1] 0.2985092
1-sum(residuals(mod)^2)/SSR_y_train
#> [1] 0.2985092
```

Compute on test data:

```r
## test
pred_test <- predict(mod, newdata = test)
y_test <- test$carb
SSR_y_test <- sum((y_test-mean(y_test))^2)

cor(pred_test, y_test)^2
#> [1] 0.01737236
rsquare(mod, test)
#> [1] -0.6769549

1- 28* var(pred_test-y_test)/SSR_y_train
#> [1] -19.31621
1- 28* var(pred_test-y_test)/SSR_y_test
#> [1] -0.6769549
```

Comment: why do you use 28 and not 29?

Answer (score 0):

```
model_1 = sm.OLS(df['ExpirationMonth'], 
                 sm.add_constant(df[['Salerank', 
                                     'X2013USSales', 
                                     'X2013WorldSales', 
                                     'ProfitMargin', 
                                     'NumStores', 
                                     'RewardSize']])).fit()

r_squared_1 = model_1.rsquared
print(f"Model 1 R-squared: {r_squared_1}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).