# Validate Accuracy of Test Data

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, test-data

I have fit my model with my training data and tested the accuracy of the model using r squared.

However, I want to test the accuracy of the model with my test data, how to do this?

My predicted value is continuous. Quite new to this so open to suggestions.

```
LR_swim <- lm(racetime_mins ~ event_month +gender + place +
             clocktime_mins +handicap_mins +
              Wind_Speed_knots+ 
             Air_Temp_Celsius +Water_Temp_Celsius +Wave_Height_m,
               data = SwimmingTrain) 
           family=gaussian(link = "identity")
summary(LR_swim)
rsq(LR_swim) #Returns-  0.9722331

#Predict Race_Time Using Test Data
 pred_LR <- predict(LR_swim, SwimmingTest, type ="response")
#Add predicted Race_Times back into the test dataset.
SwimmingTest$Pred_RaceTime <- pred_LR
```

Comment: Accuracy is a metric while modeling the categorical variables. So if you have a non-categorical variables in your model as a dependent variable while using linear regression, R^2 is the right metric. It is nothing but the explained sum of square over total sum of square ratio. It gives you the fitting performance of your data under the OLS assumptions.

Comment: An intuitive metric, although perhaps not so common outside of environmental science, is the [Nash-Sutcliffe coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash%E2%80%93Sutcliffe_model_efficiency_coefficient). Essentially, it measures how well your model predicts observations and is closely related to R². It's implemented in the [`topmodel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topmodel/index.html) package as `NSEff`. You pass your observations and your predictions and the function returns a value in the interval (-∞,1] with 1 indicating perfect predictions.

Comment: But broadly it sounds like you're interested in [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

Comment: @maydin thanks for your reply, do you know how to apply this method to my test set in r? ie. how to run rsquared for 'pred_LR' in my code

Comment: @Lyngbakr thanks for reply, I'll look into this also.

Comment: @KateEnglish There is a discussion about your question at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691127/r-squared-on-test-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, as already pointed out in the comments, the term *accuracy* is actually reserved for classification problems. What you are actually referring to is the performance of your model. And truth is, for *regression* problems (such as yours), there are several such performance measures available.

For good or bad, R^2 is still the standard measure in several implementations; nevertheless, it may be helpful to keep in mind what I have argued [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct/54618898#54618898):

> the whole R-squared concept comes in fact directly from the world of statistics, where the emphasis is on *interpretative* models, and it has little use in machine learning contexts, where the emphasis is clearly on *predictive* models; at least AFAIK, and beyond some very introductory courses, I have never (I mean *never*...) seen a predictive modeling problem where the R-squared is used for any kind of performance assessment; neither it's an accident that popular *machine learning* introductions, such as Andrew Ng's [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) at Coursera, do not even bother to mention it. And, as noted in the [Github thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5570) above (emphasis added):
>
> > In particular when using a **test** set, it's a bit unclear to me what the R^2 means.
>
> with which I certainly concur.

There are several other performance measures that are arguably more suitable in a *predictive* task, such as yours; and most of them can be implemented with a simple line of R code. So, for some dummy data:

```
preds <- c(1.0, 2.0, 9.5)
actuals <- c(0.9, 2.1, 10.0)
```

the [mean squared error (MSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) is simply

```
mean((preds-actuals)^2)
# [1] 0.09
```

while the [mean absolute error (MAE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error), is

```
mean(abs(preds-actuals))
# [1] 0.2333333
```

and the [root mean squared error (RMSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) is simply the square root of the MSE, i.e.:

```
sqrt(mean((preds-actuals)^2))
# [1] 0.3
```

These measures are arguably more useful for assessing the performance on *unseen* data. The last two have an additional advantage of being in the same scale as your original data (not the case for MSE).

Comment: Very good explaination. There is one important thing to clarify, MSE, MAE, and RMSE are the metrics for prediction power rather than the fitting performance. However it was asked the prediction power metrics I guess, that is why she confused the R2 for Accuracy. And that makes this answer the right one.

Comment: @desertnaut many thanks for our informative answer, can the R^2 value be computed the same way, with simple r-scripts, such as those used for MSE, MAE and RMSE?

Comment: @KateEnglish see [Function to calculate R2 (R-squared) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901445/function-to-calculate-r2-r-squared-in-r)